# Centering table in landscape page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, landscape

I'm trying to get a table centered both vertically and horizontally in a landscape page. I've tried some of the solutions proposed around here but I can't get them to work in my specific case.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htb!]
    \centering
    \tiny
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|ll|*4r|*4r|*4r|*4r|*4r|}
    % ...
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A very wide table}
    \label{tab:wide_table}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102366/21891) may be of interest.

Comment: By using `[htb!]` you have prevented the one float area that vertically centers. You could use `[p]`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Merely to try and provide a minimal working example, I would like to propose the following, adding to the questioner's input the suggestions in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[p]
        \centering
        \tiny
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{|ll|*4r|*4r|*4r|*4r|*4r|}
        % ...
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A very wide table}
        \label{tab:wide_table}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Here I assumed that package `lscape` is used for the landscape environment, and `float` for the `[htb!]` argument, which is changed to `[p]` for the vertical alignment as David Carlisle pointed out.

Maybe practical for vertically centering other things than tables and figures (that don't take the `[p]` argument) is this other example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{table}[htb!]
        \centering
        \tiny
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{|ll|*4r|*4r|*4r|*4r|*4r|}
        % ...
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A very wide table}
        \label{tab:wide_table}
    \end{table}
    \vspace*{\fill}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The trick in this case is in  the `\vspace*{\fill}`, as was proposed in this other thread: [Vertically center text on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/vertically-center-text-on-a-page).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. \topskip0pt caused my tables to have an extra blank page in my project.